# How do I set react params to change api request on server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to dynamically render data to a react app from an external api using express.

My react component has a state that controls which page to fetch from the api.

What I want to achieve is when I click Load More button, the component sends to express next page number send back data.

This is what i've tried, but with no success:

Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    const page = req.query.pages;
    let url = `https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=${page}`;
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((contents) =>
        res.send({
            products: contents.products,
            nextPage: contents.nextPage
        })
    );
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

react component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const Products = () => {
    const [ products, setProducts ] = useState([]);
    const [ page, setPage ] = useState(1);
    const loadProduct = () => {
        setPage(page + 1);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products?pages=${page}`).then((response) => response.json()).then((contents) => {
            setProducts([ ...products, ...contents.products ]);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map((product) => <p>{product.name}</p>)}
            <button type="submit" onClick={loadProduct}>
                Load More
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Products;
```

Comment: can you please make sure that when you are clicking 'Load More' button then the API is being called properly?

Comment: Do you need to use an effect here? I'm wondering if you could just have it be it's own function. Then executing that function in the success callback of the state change, to make it synchronous.

Comment: I think you need to add the `page` value in the useEffect array ( second argument of the function ).

Comment: @HiteshLala it worked adding page to second argument. Thanks !